# Web Application Class Design Advice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web application is going to consist of some people information. Basically in my database I will have fields such as

```
personid              autoid               clubid              personalinfoid
fname                 carmodel             clubname            personid 
mname                 cartype              clubaddress         height
lname                 carcolor                                 ethnicity
address               license#                                 driverslicense#
address2              boattype                                 
homephone             boatsize
cellphone
```

I am not worried about the table design just did this for an example.

Edited my question to try to make it more clear. How would you approach designing classes for a web application of this nature. Should I have separate classes for each table?

What I had in mind was to create a properties class that holds all the fields and properties gets and sets everything from the db. Then creating a person.cs, auto.cs, personinfo.cs, and clubs.cs classes would this be the right way to do this?

Comment: If I were you I would begin by removing the word "person" from in front of every property/field name you use. The relationship to a "person" entity should be clear from the way you set up your objects & design.

Comment: It speaks to how you are conceptualizing the information. A "person club" (to me) is something that defines a relationship between a "person" and a "club" -- e.g. a membership -- not an object entity. You woudn't repeat the name and address of every club for every person who's a member of it. The club is unique. Separate "person" from the objects. Think about the unique entities. Then describe the realtionships.

Comment: i took person out but like I said that was just an example these are not my real fields there are no real fields yet I am just trying to understand how to approach a project of this nature

Comment: Tim, the best approach would be to first learn as much as possible by reading on how to do object-oriented data access. The question suggests that you are not familiar with existing approaches, just to name Linq2SQL or Entity Framework. By studying these, you could clearly answer your question by yourself easily.

Answer (score 0):

What you have suggested makes sense and is what Object to Database frameworks do!

If you were using [Entity Framewor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx)k for example, you could create you classes first (imaginatively called "code first") and then EF would generate the database for you. Equally you could do "database first" and create you database schema then EF will generate the classes for you. Personally I prefer the former as it gives you a bit more control with database versioning.

There are a plethora of other frameworks available and this is just one example.

So your `PersonalInfo` object would look something like this using EF:

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //EF will automatically figure out this is your PK
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public string DriversLicence { get; set; }

    //EF automatically figures out that the PersonId property refers to your Person table
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } //navigation property so you can do personalInfo.Person.FirstName

}
```